# Using properties file from jar file

Tags: java, properties, maven-2, pom.xml

I have a Maven project. The project `pom.xml` contains a dependent jar file in which the `x.properties` file is present.

Now, this `x.properties` file have some variable declared in it like -

`excel.location = ${root.folder}`

`root.folder` is defined in the pom.xml as -

```
<properties>
<root.folder>${project.basedir}/Test</root.folder>
</properties>
```

When I read the properties file from jar file (using ClassLoader) I don't get the actual variable value (i.e. resource filtering is not achieved).

How can I achieve this?

**how do I filter resources from dependent jar**

Comment: @Xabster it's mainly in config rather than in code. anything specific you want?

Answer (score 0):

Resource filtering will only occur when the jar is built - i.e. when `mvn package` is run on the project. If it is in a dependent jar, nothing will be filtered as the jar has already been built elsewhere.

It seems like when *that* jar was built, filtering was not done.